# How to show custom labels in x-axis of Aspose graphs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose, aspose-cells

I have a aspose Column3DClustered graph.Currently the x-axis is showing values in numbers only say 1,2...I want to show some labels like "Apple","Orange" etc..instead of 1,2etc..How can I achieve this using aspose?

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

worksheet.Cells[0, 0].PutValue(1);
worksheet.Cells[0, 1].PutValue(50);
worksheet.Cells[0, 2].PutValue(100);

worksheet.Cells[1, 0].PutValue(2);
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].PutValue(50);
worksheet.Cells[1, 2].PutValue(20);


int chartIndex = worksheet.Charts.Add(ChartType.Column3DClustered, 5, 0, 15, 5);
Chart chart = worksheet.Charts[chartIndex];
chart.Title.Text = "Fruits for period 6/2016";

chart.Title.Font.Size = 6;
chart.NSeries.Add("B1:B2", true);
chart.NSeries.Add("C1:C2", true);

chart.NSeries[0].Name = "Total Quantity";
chart.NSeries[1].Name = "Net Available";
chart.NSeries[0].DataLabels.ShowValue = true;
chart.NSeries[0].DataLabels.Font.Size = 6;
chart.NSeries[0].Area.ForegroundColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
chart.NSeries[1].DataLabels.ShowValue = true;
chart.NSeries[1].DataLabels.Font.Size = 6;
chart.NSeries[1].Area.ForegroundColor = Color.MediumPurple;
chart.Legend.Position = LegendPositionType.Bottom;
chart.Legend.Font.Size = 6;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **Chart.NSeries.CategoryData** for your needs. Please see the following sample code. It loads the sample Excel file and changes **Category Data i.e. X-axis** of the chart and saves it as output Excel file.

**C#**

```
//Load the sample Excel file.
Workbook wb = new Workbook("Sample.xlsx");

//Access first worksheet.
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//Access first chart.
Chart ch = ws.Charts[0];

//Change the category data - X axis values.
ch.NSeries.CategoryData = "=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$4";

//Save the output Excel file.
wb.Save("Output.xlsx");
```

Please see this image. It shows the sample Excel file, output Excel file and the effect of the code on them for your reference.

[image: Change CategoryData X Axis of the Chart using Aspose.Cells APIs]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: It is good to know that the answer was helpful for you. Thank you and have a good day,